# Como puedo hacer que un sonido suene cada cierto tiempo?

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy intentando realizar que cuando una mano pasa una coordenada, suene un sonido. El problema surge al pasar la mano , que se intenta ejecutar constantemente ya que es un sonido de unos 2 segundos. Se podría hacer de alguna forma que lo haga cada cierto tiempo?

```
//Sector 3
if (FuncionActivada == 1 && VariablesGlobales.HandRightX >= 0.38 && VariablesGlobales.HandRightY >= 0.35 && VariablesGlobales.HandRightZ >= 0.9
    && VariablesGlobales.HandRightZ <= 1.3)
{
    SoundPlayer miSonido3 = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\Ring03.wav");
    miSonido3.Play();
}
```

Comment: perdón por la respuesta errónea, no vi el wpf, enseguida actualizo mi respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías poner un `timer`:

```
DispatcherTimer dispathcer  = new DispatcherTimer();

//Intervalo de 1 segundo
dispatcher.Interval = new TimeSpan (0,0,1);
dispatcher.Tick += (s, a) => {
//la función a ejecutar, en este caso el sonido
}
dispathcer.Start();
```

Comment: ese timer donde se encuentra??

Comment: estoy usando WPF no Forms

Comment: @DanielPotrimba actualizada

Comment: Alberto, he probado con el dispatcherTimer pero hace mal, entra en un bucle del que no sale

Comment: @DanielPotrimba entonces añade una condición y en ella especifícas cuando quieres que este pare con `timer.Stop();`

Comment: mmm voy a probar :)

Answer (score 1):

Implemente una pequeña solución que cuando pasas el mouse sobre un rectángulo muestra en un label "beep.." y luego de terminar de sonar espera cinco segundos y se apaga.

Le agregue que muestre los ticks para que veas que no importa cuantas veces entres y salgas de rectángulo no vuelve a sonar hasta que termine el anterior.

Utilizo BackgroundWorker para controlar el flujo de ejecución en un hilo.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTimer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter"/>
    <Label Name="lblSalida" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="392"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfTimer
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    BackgroundWorker parlante;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        parlante = new BackgroundWorker();
        parlante.DoWork += sonar;
        parlante.RunWorkerCompleted += apagar;
    }

    private void sonar(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Reproducir sonido
        //demorar hasta el siguiente beep
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void apagar(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblSalida.Content = "";
    }

    private void Rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!parlante.IsBusy)
        {
            lblSalida.Content = "beep.. " + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            parlante.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
}
```